# Wordpress require_once( ) - path returning an error

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 
require_once (bloginfo('template_url') . '/form_producer/form_producer.php');
$form_prod_url = bloginfo('template_url').'/form_producer';
?>
```

How can I edit the PHP above to include 'form_producer.php' and the file 'form_producer'.

All this does is return an error and I'm unsure why.

EDIT: I have changed bloginfo to ('template_url') which is where the folders are. Still returning errors

Comment: Under no circumstance tell us *what* error you are getting - that would take away all the fun of guessing! :) (You can see the error in the syntax highlighting though, in the third line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `include` statement, use `template_directory` (the physical path) instead of `template_url` (the URL):

```
require_once (bloginfo('template_directory') . '/form_producer/form_producer.php');
```

for the URL, I don't understand which path you want to create. If you want to point to the `form_producer` directory, your

```
$form_prod_url = bloginfo('template_url').'/form_producer';
```

should work. If it doesn't, show us what those strings contain and how they vary from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error in your second line, try this

```
<?php 
require_once (get_bloginfo('url') . 'form_producer/form_producer.php');
$form_prod_url = get_bloginfo('url').'/form_producer';
?>
```

Comment: Nope, still returns bad news. Check out www.tomrawcliffe.com